# How get mark of index?

Tags: table-of-contents, bookmarks

I want get this bookmarks.

[image]

**but i only get this:**

[image]

Is there a way to get this index with the markers in the image?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[pdftex, bookmarksnumbered,  pagebackref, colorlinks=true, citecolor=Blue, linkcolor=DarkBlue!30!Black, urlcolor=Black,bookmarksopen]{hyperref}
\makeindex[columns=3, title=Alphabetical Index, intoc]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Dedicatory}
   to all my family
\chapter*{Abstract}
   hello world
\chapter{chapter}
\section{Introduction}
In this example several keywords\index{keywords} will be 
used which are important and deserve to appear in the 
Index\index{Index}.
 \subsection{subsection}
Terms like generate\index{generate} and some\index{others} 
will also show up. Terms in the index can also be 
nested \index{Index!nested}

\clearpage

\section{Second section}
This second section\index{section} may include some special 
word, and expand the ones already used\index{keywords!used}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\usepackage{hyperref}` to your preamble and recompile twice.

Comment: @leandriis but i need the tree of image

Comment: @leandriis i edited my question

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? I think part of you problem is that you use starred commands (such as \chapter*) which do not show in the table of contents

Comment: @sheß i want show the bookmark 
as in the first image that I put, Dedicatory and abstract should locate in up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add them e.g. with pdfbookmark:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[pdftex, bookmarksnumbered,  pagebackref, colorlinks=true, citecolor=Blue, linkcolor=DarkBlue!30!Black, urlcolor=Black,bookmarksopen]{hyperref}
\makeindex[columns=3, title=Alphabetical Index, intoc]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark{Dedicatory}{dedic}
\chapter*{Dedicatory}

   to all my family

\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark{Abstract}{abstr}

\chapter*{Abstract}

   hello world


\chapter{chapter}
\section{Introduction}
In this example several keywords\index{keywords} will be
used which are important and deserve to appear in the
Index\index{Index}.
 \subsection{subsection}
Terms like generate\index{generate} and some\index{others}
will also show up. Terms in the index can also be
nested \index{Index!nested}

\clearpage

\section{Second section}
This second section\index{section} may include some special
word, and expand the ones already used\index{keywords!used}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much, but still need to put the parent nodes, "start" and "index general" (see figure 1 please)

Comment: Use `\pdfbookmark[-1]{Start}{start}` for the start node, and figure out  yourself how to get index general.

Comment: with [-1] 
it is not at the same level as in my first figure

Comment: Don't use -1 for index general, if you don't want to have it at the same level as start. And make an educated guess what the -1 is doing and how you can use this optional argument to arrange the levels to your liking.